# Modify the order of two blocks of legend - not sure of how to use guide_legend()

Tags: r, legend

I would like to change the order of the legend blocks in the graph attached so that the legend for "Observed" values is on top of "Modeled" values and not the opposite as it is at the moment. Here is an R script to illustrate my question:

```
#Dataframes to illustrate my question
A <- c(10,20,30,40, 50, 70)
B <- c(20,10,30,10, 6, 1)
C <- c("treat1","treat1", "treat1", "treat2", "treat2", "treat2" )
Modeled <- as.data.frame(cbind(A, B, C))
colnames(Modeled) <- c("varX", "varY", "treat")
E <- c(10,0,20,0, 6, 10)
obs <- as.data.frame(cbind(A, E, C))
colnames(obs) <- c("varX", "varY", "variable")

#plotting
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Modeled, aes(varX, varY))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(group=treat, colour=treat, linetype=treat)) 
p <- p + geom_point(data=obs, aes(x=varX, y=varY, shape=variable), size=3)
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(name='Modeled', values=c('black','grey'))
p <- p + scale_linetype_manual(name='Modeled', values=c('solid','dashed'))
p <- p + scale_shape_manual(name='Observed', values=c(16,24) )
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

Before guide function:

[image]

I have tried the `guide()` function as suggested in another post on the website. see script below. But it duplicated the legend 'Modeled'.

```
p <- ggplot(Modeled, aes(varX, varY))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(group=treat, colour=treat, linetype=treat)) 
p <- p + geom_point(data=obs, aes(x=varX, y=varY, shape=variable), size=3)
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(name='Modeled', values=c('black','grey'))
p <- p + scale_linetype_manual(name='Modeled', values=c('solid','dashed'))
p <- p + scale_shape_manual(name='Observed', values=c(16,24) )
p <- p + guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1), 
         shape = guide_legend(order = 2))
p <- p + theme_bw()
p
```

[image]

Comment: change the order of the `geom_line` and `geom_point` in your first code block

Comment: Thank you Pascal for your reply. The problem is that the legend Modeled is duplicated...= it is displayed twice even when trying your suggestion. Any idea?

Comment: @user20650, thank you. However it does not work for me with the example I am giving to write the line geom_point before geom_line.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set "linetype" order (**linetype=guide_legend(order=2)**) as the same as the "colour". The second "Modeled legend" indicates the "linetype" (the treat 2 legend is a dash black line) whereas the first "Modeled legend" indicates the "colour" (the treat2 legend is a solid gray line), thus use this instead:

```
p <- p + guides(linetype=guide_legend(order=2), 
                    colour=guide_legend(order=2), shape=guide_legend(order=1))
```

here is the final figure:
[image: Observed is on top of Modeled]